# How do I detect laser point?

Tags: lasers

I know military uses laser designators and they can be visible by their bombs or missiles from really long range. My question is how could I do such laser point tracking device? Lets say I point laser at wall and I want to detect its position. Should I use flir camera? Or is there specific laser detectors/scanners for such thing? I'm talking about hobby-level prices.

Comment: What wavelength laser are you using?

Comment: Maybe this article is relevant. http://www.conspiracyoflight.com/Quadrant/Quadrant.html